# App crashes when menuItem is pressed to display Custom Adapter for listview in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

I am trying to display a listview whenever menuItem is pressed. I want to display custom layout , for that I need custom adapter for list view which isn't working properly and my app is crashing. I have 3-4 custom adapter in my android app which were working fine, but since when i added another one... the previous one also stopped working i dont know why!! I have also seen almost every question related to this on many forums but nothing works for me. Please help me where i am wrong..

Below is my code for menuItems..

```
  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
            case R.id.settings:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, OpenSettings.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.debacha:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(AyahsDisplay.this,DebachaDisplay.class);
                this.startActivity(intent1);
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
    }
```

when menu item with id "debacha" is pressed, I am starting new activity in which I am intended to display custom listview where i am getting error and app crashes..

Code for that part is below...

```
public class DebachaDisplay extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView list1;
    ArrayList<debacha> debachas = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_debacha_display);

        try {
            parseXML(); //here i am parsing XML file to load data in "debachas" which is working fine
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) { }
        catch (IOException e) { }

    }

private void printDebacha(ArrayList<debacha> debachas){
    list1 = findViewById(R.id.debachaList);
    CustomDebachaview customDebachaview = new CustomDebachaview(DebachaDisplay.this,debachas);
    list1.setAdapter(customDebachaview);
}
```

Below is layout file for DisplayDebacha activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DebachaDisplay">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/debachaList"
        android:background="#FDFFE9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Below is the code for my Custom adaptor class...

```
package com.example.demo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomDebachaview extends ArrayAdapter<debacha> {
    private ArrayList<debacha> debachas;
    private Activity context;
    public CustomDebachaview(Activity context,ArrayList<debacha> debachas){
        super(context,R.layout.debacha_list_view,debachas);
        this.debachas = debachas;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position , @Nullable View convertView , @Nullable final ViewGroup parent){
        View r = convertView;
        CustomDebachaview.viewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if(r == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            r = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.debacha_list_view,null,true);
            viewHolder = new CustomDebachaview.viewHolder(r);
            r.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (CustomDebachaview.viewHolder) r.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.Dnumber.setText("﴾ " + debachas.get(position).getDNumber() + " ﴿");
        viewHolder.Dname.setText(debachas.get(position).getDName());

        return r;
    }

    class viewHolder{
        TextView Dnumber;
        TextView Dname;
        viewHolder(View v){
            Dname = v.findViewById(R.id.Dnumber);
            Dname = v.findViewById(R.id.Dname);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is custom adapter list view layout file code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Dnumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="debacha number"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="#297B16"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Dname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dname"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textColor="#226A12"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am getting following errors..

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.demo, PID: 1040
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.demo.CustomDebachaview.getView(CustomDebachaview.java:42)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:3219)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2219)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:827)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:888)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1958)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2991)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22407)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6589)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1801)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1567)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22407)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6589)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22407)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6589)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22407)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6589)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22407)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6589)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22407)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6589)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:1075)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22407)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6589)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3371)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2840)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1888)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8503)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7073)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1040 SIG: 9
Process 1040 terminated.
```

Any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: you should never have a try catch statement and not log or at least handle the exception: `try {
            parseXML(); //here i am parsing XML file to load data in "debachas" which is working fine
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) { }
        catch (IOException e) { }` although this is irrelevant to your issue, post your error logs too please

Comment: @a_local_nobody I have edited my question with error logs.. can u please see and tell what might be the problem ?

Comment: I think my viewHolder object in getView method of CustomAdapter class is Null maybe... i dont know why if that's the case

Answer (score 0):

My bad... that was just a silly mistake, a typo in viewholder constructor which is making Dnumber null :(

```
 class viewHolder{
        TextView Dnumber;
        TextView Dname;
        viewHolder(View v){
            Dname = v.findViewById(R.id.Dnumber);
            Dname = v.findViewById(R.id.Dname);
        }
    }
```

I am initialising 2 time Dname.

Lesson learned: DO CHECK YOUR TYPOS :)